# Minimize $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{x_{i}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $x, a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}_{++}$ and define 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(x) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{x_{i}}\right).
\end{align}
Find the minimizer $x$ of $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Simply write that $\nabla L = 0$ and you get the minimum.

Comment: Is it convex? @Gribouillis

Comment: I don't know if it's convex but there's only one direction where $\nabla L=0$ and it is homogeneous of degree 0 ($L(\lambda x) = L(x)$). If all the $a_i>0$, there is a minimum somewhere at a point where all the $x_i>0$, so it can be only in the direction where $\nabla L=0$

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality $(\sum x_i)(\sum a_i/x_i)=(\sum (\sqrt{x_i})^2)(\sum (\sqrt{a_i}/\sqrt{x_i})^2)\geq(\sum(\sqrt{x_i}\sqrt{a_i}/\sqrt{x_i}))^2=(\sum \sqrt{a_i})^2$. The equality is obtained when the vectors $(\sqrt{x_i})$ and $(\sqrt{a_i}/\sqrt{x_i})$ are proportional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{a_i} \right)^2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{a_i}{x_i}} \right)^2 \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{x_i} \right).
$$
The equality in Cauchy-Schwarz takes place iff $x_i^2 = ba_i$ for some $b$.

Comment: I see $x = b \sqrt{a}$ instead of $x = b a$

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks, fixed